# How to maintain factors when using plot_ly inside a function in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr, plotly, r-factor

I am trying to put a `plot_ly` barplot inside a function so that I can change the variable to plot when needed. The code works perfectly outside of the function, but does not work in the context of being inside a function.
The problem is that `plot_ly` barplot no longer treats the x-variable as a `factor`, despite it being a `factor` in the `data.frame` (verified after testing).

Also, an explanation as to why I have to use `enquo()` and `{{}}` to parse the variables in the `dplyr` context and the `plotly` context, respectively would be appreciated.

Code (comments are attempts at restoring the factor):

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(x = as.factor(sample(1:3, n, replace = T)), 
                   y = rnorm(n))

summary_plot <- function(df, var){
  quo_var <- enquo(var)
  
  data.frame(df %>%
               group_by({{var}}) %>%
               summarise(n = n())) %>%
  plot_ly(
    # x = ~as.factor(quo_var),
    # x = as.factor(~quo_var),
    x = ~quo_var,
    y = ~n,
    type = "bar"
  )
  
}

summary_plot(df, x)
```

[image: plot_ly output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your error. It works as factors for me when using either numbers or letters too. Maybe try updating your `plotly::`, `ggplot::` and `dplyr::` packages?

- The `enquo()` is required to quote the variable held within the function argument, otherwise the group_by and plotly will look for a column in your dataset called `var` and fail. The normal way to pass this to the inside functions would be `!!quo_var` but since `plot_ly()` uses the formula notation to look for variables within the data frame with `x = ~..` you didn't need the `!!`, and you can also use `x = quo_var` without the `~`
- Now, `group_by()` which is a part of tidyverse has a shortcut to avoid the `enquo() .. !!.` workflow by directly using `{{var}}` as a convenient shorthand

> When you have the data-variable in a function argument (i.e. an env-variable that holds a promise2), you need to embrace the argument by surrounding it in doubled braces, like filter(df, {{ var }}).
> [programming with dplyr/Indirection section](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

[image]

Comment: This is the answer: "you can also use `x = quo_var` without the `~`". Thanks. These packages and their syntax are so confusing!